# How to validate the unix timestamp in java?

Tags: java, unix-timestamp

I need validate the given input String is a valid `Timestamp` in milliseconds.

For example if the given `Timestamp`

```
String time ="1310966356458";
```

Then it should return true.

if

```
String time ="1000";
```

then it should return false;

Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why is 1000 not a valid timestamp? 1000 milliseconds after 0:00 on 1.1.1970?

Comment: Why should `1000` be not a valid timestamp? It is `Thu Jan 01 00:00:01 +0000 1970`. In fact, any valid integer (even negative) is a valid UNIX timestamp.

Comment: 1000 ms after epoch is still a valid timestamp. You should define a range of sensible timestamps. The sensible range is then case specific, maybe you expect entries after 2010 for example.

Comment: Please help how to define proper range of timestamp

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We cannot tell you what is sensible for your application. If there was a limit which was correct for every situation it would be built in.  It could be that only timestamps after you developed your application and not in the future are sensible.

```
public static final String RELEASE_DATE = "2011/06/17";
private static final long MIN_TIMESTAMP;

static {
    try {
        MIN_TIMESTAMP = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd").parse(RELEASE_DATE).getTime();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        throw new AssertionError(e);
    }
}

// after the software was release and not in the future.
public static final boolean validTimestamp(long ts) {
    return ts >= MIN_TIMESTAMP && ts <= System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

However, it could be that the timestamp represents when someone was born. In which case the minimum timestamp could be negative.

It could be that the timestamp is the time when something expires (like tickets) Some will be in the past (perhaps not before this year) and some will be in the future. (perhaps not more than 2 years in advance.)

---

Times can be negative. Man landed on the moon before 1970 so the timestamp would be negative.

```
String MAN_ON_MOON = "1969/07/21 02:56 GMT";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm Z");
System.out.println(sdf.parse(MAN_ON_MOON).getTime());
```

prints

```
-14159040000
```

Comment: Upvoting for sheer common sense.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just subtract the epoch time from the time you're given. If the result is negative, then it's not valid.

Comment: ... unless you can have times before 1970. ;)

Comment: He is asking for Java not for assembler ;-)

Comment: Peter, you need a coffee. :) Did man land on the moon before midnight 1 Jan 1970? 0 - -1415094000 = 1415094000, meaning that the moon landing occurred before. Remember, in mathematics, two negatives make a positive, even though your school teachers would have said otherwise, two wrongs make a right!

Answer (score 0):

Very old question but here is how I did it:

```
   boolean isNumberValue(String value) {
      //TODO - check if is number
      String regex = "^[0-9]+$";
      Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
      Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(value);
      boolean matchFound = matcher.find();

      if(matchFound) {
           //System.out.println("Match found");
           return true;
      } else {
          //System.out.println("Match not found");
          return false;
      }
   }

   boolean isTimestamp(String timestamp) {      
        try {
            long time = Long.valueOf(timestamp);
            Date date = new Date((long)time);
            long dateOld = date.getTime();
            //if no exception was raised, then its unix and only digits
            if(!isNumberValue(String.valueOf(dateOld))) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
      
   }

   if (isTimestamp(1679308838)){
       System.out.println("Is unix timestamp");
   }else{
       System.out.println("NOT unix timestamp");
   }
```