# How to validate Unix Timestamp in Java?

Tags: android

I have an Android application that stores a unix timestamp of a certain event in shared preferences. Since those files can be accessed (and modified) by anyone who has a rooted phone, I'm applying a validation check in my app before processing that value. So, my question is, how can a unix timestamp be validated?

For example

```
String timestamp = "1415251687";
validateUnixTime(timestamp);
```

should return `true` and

```
timestamp = "1415-dummydata";
validateUnixTime(timestamp);
```

should return `false`

**Edit:** Just to be clear, I'm storing (and fetching) the value of timestamp as `long` from shared preferences. The code above was just for the sake of simplicity. The function should accept a `long` as its parameter, validate it, and return `true` or `false` based on it being a valid unix timestamp value.

Comment: you're actually talking about validating a String not Timestamp

Comment: @AbdallahAlaraby It was just for the sake of example. I am storing the timestamp as `long` in the shared preferences file. Please check the edited question.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on when do you want the Timestamp to be considered invalid. but the following code (that i got from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6733768/2185634)) might help you get the main idea.

```
public static final String RELEASE_DATE = "2011/06/17";
private static final long MIN_TIMESTAMP;

static {
    try {
        MIN_TIMESTAMP = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(RELEASE_DATE).getTime();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        throw new AssertionError(e);
    }
}

// after the software was release and not in the future.
public static final boolean validTimestamp(long ts) {
    return ts >= MIN_TIMESTAMP && ts <= System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

Comment: The scope of this functionality is fundamentally different than mine. But I get what you meant by this. I will try the similar approach.

Answer (score 0):

First convert the Timestamp to human readable date.

```
long dv = Long.valueOf(timestamp_in_string)*1000;// its need to be in milisecond
Date df = new java.util.Date(dv);
String vv = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(df);
if(isValidDate(vv){
     Log.d("DateIsValid","true");
} else {
     Log.d("DateIsValid","false");
}
```

then check if the date converted is valid or not

```
public static boolean isValidDate(String inDate) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    dateFormat.setLenient(false);
    try {
      dateFormat.parse(inDate.trim());
    } catch (ParseException pe) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

Comment: That sounds doable. Let me try that.

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat` generates a lint suppression suggestion as follows: "To get local formatting use getDateInstance(), getDateTimeInstance(), or getTimeInstance(), or use new SimpleDateFormat(String template, Locale locale) with for example Locale.US for ASCII dates."

Comment: suppress this warning. I have no idea why is it giving.

Comment: A/c to it, a newer `SimpleDateFormat` accepts second parameter `Locale`, so I passed `Locale.US` and the warning went away.